# Call class method from inside array_map anonymous function

Tags: php, class, object, scope, array-map

I am trying to call one of my object's methods from within an `array_map` anonymous function. So far I am receiving the expected error of:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in...

I know why I am getting this error, I just don't know a way to achieve what I am trying to... Does anybody have any suggestions?

Here is my current code:

```
// Loop through the data and ensure the numbers are formatted correctly
array_map(function($value){
    return $this->some_method($value,'value',false);
},$this->mssql->data[0]['results'][0]);
```

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.4, which added support for `$this` in closures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell the function to "close over" the $this variable by using the "use" keyword

```
$host = $this;
array_map(function($value) use ($host) {
    return $host->some_method($value,'value',false);
},$this->mssql->data[0]['results'][0]);
```

Comment: You do not need to pass objects by reference like `&$object`, because objects are already passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can call your map function from a class context and you will not receive any errors. Like:

```
class A {

        public $mssql = array(
                'some output'
            );

        public function method()
        {
            array_map(function($value){
                return $this->mapMethod($value,'value',false);
            },$this->mssql);

        }

        public function mapMethod($value)
        {
            // your map callback here
            echo $value; 

        }


    }

    $a = new A();

    $a->method();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing!

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not so sure that your code look exactly the same, because you sould not receive that error if you do so, and i'm pretty sure.