# How add a link on comma separated multidimensional array

Tags: php

How add a link using the id on comma separated multidimensional array?

What I done so far:

```
$string = implode(", ", array_column($title_genres, "name"));
echo $string;
```

My array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#66 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Aventure"
    ["tmdb_id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
   }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#67 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Animation"
    ["tmdb_id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
   }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#63 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Familial"
    ["tmdb_id"]=>
    string(5) "10751"
   }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#70 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Fantastique"
    ["tmdb_id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to wrap each `name` in an `a` tag, with the `id` as part of the `href` url?

Comment: @IncredibleHat  YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a simple foreach on $title_genres to build a new array of just linked names, then you can do the implode on that to output with commas:

```
$links = array();
foreach($title_genres as $item) {
    $links[] = '<a href="/some.php?id='. $item['id'] .'">'. $item['name'] .'</a>';
}
echo implode(', ',$links);
```

Update 1: In case you are using stdClass objects:

```
$links = array();
foreach($title_genres as $item) {
    $links[] = '<a href="/some.php?id='. $item->id .'">'. $item->name .'</a>';
}
echo implode(', ',$links);
```

Update 2: An all in one line mash using array_map ;)

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($a){
                        return '<a href="/some.php?id='. $a->id .'">'. $a->name .'</a>';
                   },$title_genres) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `array_map` solution, you decide if you consider it simpler than `foreach`.

```
$string = implode(",", array_map(function($item) {
    return "<a href='/some.php?id={$item->id'}'>{$item->name}</a>";
}, $title_genres));
echo $string;
```

If the base URL is in a variable, you can access it using a `use()` declaration.

```
$baseurl = base_url();
$string = implode(",", array_map(function($item) use ($baseurl) {
    return "<a href='$baseurl/some.php?id={$item->id'}'>{$item->name}</a>";
}, $title_genres));
```

Comment: How add a variable  to array_map?

Comment: If you mean how to allow the function to access an outside variable, add the `use($variable)` declaration before the `{`.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't work, Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the variable?

Comment: I have a function call "base_url()" and several variables and I can't use them in array_map

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: You asked me about including a variable in the function. I assumed you would do `$baseurl = base_url();` before calling the function.

Comment: @MappyLord If your base_url() function is outside a class, you can just use it inside the array_map anonymous function like you would anywhere else. If your base_url() is a method inside of a class, then here is more information on using methods inside the array_map anonymous function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316623/call-class-method-from-inside-array-map-anonymous-function